# Save xml column data in physical path using java

Tags: java, xml, database

I have an sql server database table which has xml column name called "Bodytext" which will store xml data.

Now I need to get this "Bodytext" column data and save into System physical path as xml file(Ex: test.xml etc.,)

Any suggestion how to implement this using JAVA?

Comment: it has little to see with xml. Retrieve text from database, and store it in a text file (named "foo.xml" if you want).

Comment: Save the data into a variable and write the file. [Trick Question?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Answer (score 0):

The column type would be BLOB or CLOB. Retrieve the column data and write the byte data to your file and make it abc.xml

Comment: or text field, why binary ?

Comment: 'Byte Data' ~ Eh why? Are you writing a serialized object to file?No.. just write an xml file.